# Forecasting amount of slippage in executing option spreads

Tags: options, spread, slippage

Is there a good quantitative model to estimate how much slippage is required to execute a particular option spread trade?

For example, let's say you want to execute an Iron Condor.  Given X, Y, Z market conditions, how much slippage does one need to give up from mid-price to have the order executed?